# Angular localization: extracting strings from ts files

Tags: angular, localization

Its known that $localize available for translation in ts files but extraction of the strings only implemented for templates. I read in [here](https://www.soluling.com/Help/Angular/Index.htm#:%7E:text=add%20%40angular%2Flocalize-,Process,localize%20function%20in%20source%20code.) that extraction of the strings from ts files should be available in Angular 10.1 version. Anyone know if its true?

Im trying to design our application short/long term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now possible to extract from .ts files with Angular CLI 10.1.0. Add the --ivy flag for now, in the future this flag will not be needed.

```
ng xi18n --ivy
```

To use the $localize token in .ts files, update this:

```
const myStr = 'This is a test';
```

To this:

```
const myStr = $localize`:@@name:This is a test`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found answer [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/32912#issuecomment-672875030). In latest `10.1.0-next.4`version you can. Instead of `ng xi18n` command you can run `localize-extract` command. They possibly will integrate it into CLI but for now you can run it directly.